# string searching / wild-card matching

Tags: file-io, node.js, performance, wildcard

Iv'e currently been working on a relatively small project for my company to have a play with, its basically a proxy in node.js, the features at the moment are relatively simple

- Caching
- Http(s)
- Blacklist
- Configurable
- etc.

Im at the stage where im building the blacklisting system, and my blacklist file is a plain file that would have each blacklisted site on a single line.

Now the blacklist would be constructed so that you could the following types blacklist values:

- google.com
- google.com/path
- ww2.google.com/path
- 202.55.66.201
- 202.55.66.[100-200]

now within node.js when a request comes in i have available to me is the requested URL from the client side, this would then be looked up in the IP Cache file, if it does not exists it gets pinged and i get the IP for that request.

So have a few bits of information at hand, 1 being the domain, 2 being the IP, 3 being the port.

Now the problem is finding the *fastest* way to check these values against the file based blacklist.

As these values are not direct lookups im not sure if putting then into an object and doing:

```
if(ip in blacklist || domain in blacklist || fullUri in blacklist)
{
    //block
}
```

Even if I did do that it would not really be beneficial as I cant check IP Ranges etc, it lacks support for the more demanding site blacklisting techniques.

I was thinking of some sort of database system but this is something I wanted to avoid, so basically what im asking is there some way to perform wild-card lookups on a datafile without causing too much overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the more efficient way would be to loop each line of the file, and compare against your information - also would allow pattern matching - so in pseudo code:

```
each file as line
    if line equal ip or line eq domain or line match 134.567.987.[0-9]{1-3}
        then block and break
```

Comment: and what if there was 2K domains blacklisted, you mean that I should do (2 direct lookups and 1 regular expression) * 2000 per request, also instead of regular epressions i would prefer to use string functions such as split, to get the min and high of [100-200] and then do a sub string for the last know dot and to a `<=>` to compare the range but still feels like it can be handled better such as `{FULL_IP : {a,b,c,d}}` abcd being each segment of the ip.

Comment: will be 2K of whatever test you devise - that is assuming you are reading from a text file that has blacklisted items on single line. You could put it all in one regex (`if line match (domain|ip|134.567.987.[0-9]{1,
3})`), but i doubt the performance would be much different.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file on booting your nodejs process. You can then process the whole file and separate in on 3 arrays (IP, domains and ports).

Searching elements on memory is fast.

You can then have a `setInterval` that reloads the contents of the file and save it to the memory to get the latest blacklist.